# Is it possible to create a file with no EOF marker?

Tags: file-io

We have an application that reads in a flat file and parses out the data.  This file contains no header information or total data with which to do a checksum.  So I would like to create test cases to make sure our application properly handles "incomplete" files.

Is there a way to create a flat file with no EOF marker?  Perhaps a tool that I can use to remove the EOF marker from an existing text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flat files do not contain an end of file marker.

Almost all modern filesystems are stream based, just a bunch of bytes on disk, they don't have record/file markers.
Any end-of-file signal is added by the std library reading the file

You should test that it deals properly with incomplete lines (ie 3 values rather than 4) and missing/differnet end of lines (CR or LF rather than CR/LF)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard EOF character - EOF is a condition returned by the method that reads from a file.  For example, in C, `getchar` will return a system-specific negative value when it reaches the end of a file.

Terminals will send back ASCII 4 (`EOT`, for end of transmission) when they are done transmitting, but this doesn't help you much as you aren't going to have `EOT`s in your files to begin with.

So, this is good news for you - all your files are going to be treated the same, and you don't have to worry about handling files with no end.